# Movie featuring a man whose skin blows fire when he becomes angry

Tags: story-identification, movie

As a child I, watched a movie with my dad. It was a good one as I recall. It was about a man whose skin blows fire when he becomes angry. I think it was from the early 80s. It was a sci-fi action movie and my dad rented it from a movie rental store.

Does anyone know what this movie is?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Hades from the Disney animated Hercules series, but that's not from the 80s.

[image: Image showing Hades blowing his top]

Comment: How about offering some details as to why you think this is a match for the question ?

Comment: Erm, because his whole body literally catches fire when he's angry?